# Using SWIG typemaps to generate overloaded Python wrapper

Tags: python, numpy, wrapper, swig, overloading

I am using SWIG to generate Python bindings for a library (lets call it `Spam`) that is written in `C++`. The library internally defines its own Vector datatype, defined in the `Spam::Vector` class.

Consider the following functions to be wrapped:

```
void ham(Spam::Vector &vec_in, Spam::Vector &vec_out);
void eggs(Spam::Vector &vec_in, double arg2, double result);
```

I would like to be able to call these functions using Python lists **AND** NumPy arrays as inputs (instead of having to create a `Spam::Vector` object in Python and then populate it using the associated C++ methods - it is very *unpythonic*).

How would I go about writing the SWIG typemap to achieve this? Also, is there a way to incorporate/leverage `numpy.i` for this purpose?

Comment: are your `vec_in` arguments meant to be const? Also what does `Spam::Vector` look like internally? That will influence how best to wrap it.

Comment: Yes, `vec_in` is constant. There is no information about what `Spam::Vector` looks like internally as the library is proprietary. I only have access to `DLLs`.

Comment: OK, but does it have a constructor that takes a pointed and an array size for example? Without that it's impossible to know how to interface it with numpy.

Comment: Yes it has a constructor which takes size as input. But I think you are missing the point of my question. I can figure out the wrapping details, however I need to know how to ensure that the function is able to take an argument that is a Python List OR Numpy Array (or any other 2 types really). I want to write wrappers that can detect the 'type' of the argument on the fly and do the appropriate conversions as necessary.

Comment: I understand that but I was hoping to write an answer that really worked for both cases.  I'll just write a short answer that outlines the principles and skips the specifics then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is with a custom typemap. Precisely what this will look like depends a lot on the type `Spam::Vector` itself. In general though you can do this with something like:

```c
%typemap(in) {
  // Maybe you'd rather check for iterable here, with this check after numpy?
  if (PyList_Check($input)) {
    $1 = ... // Code to iterate over a list and prepare a Spam::Vector
  }
  else if (PyType_IsSubtype($input->ob_type, NumpyType)) {
    $1 = ... // Code to convert from numpy input
  }
  else {
    // code to raise an error
  }
}
```

There are various hacks that might be possible in other more specific circumstances, but this is the general solution.